# How the "as" attribute of xsl:template affects the result of xsl:apply-templates

Tags: xslt-2.0

Given this source document:

```
<things>
  <thing><duck>Eider</duck></thing>
  <thing><duck>Mallard</duck></thing>
  <thing><duck>Muscovy</duck></thing>
</things>
```

I require the following output

```
Fat Eider, Fat Mallard, Fat Muscovy
```

which I can indeed get with this XSL transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of separator=", ">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//duck"/>
    </xsl:value-of>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="duck" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Fat ', .)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, I have three questions:

**Question 1.** (specific)

If I remove `as="xs:string"` from the duck template, I get the following output:

```
    Fat EiderFat MallardFat Muscovy
```

Why? My understanding is that in XSLT 2.0 the result of `xsl:apply-templates` is always a sequence, and that `xsl:value-of` inserts its `separator` between the items in the sequence. So why does the sequence seem to "collapse" when the template has no `as` attribute?  Bonus points for pointing me towards appropriate pages of Michael Kay's excellent "XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0, 4th Edition" book.

**Question 2.** (vague!)

As a novice user of XSLT, it seems to me that there are probably many ways to solve this problem. Can you put forward a good solution that takes a different approach?  How do you choose between approaches?

**Question 3.**

Debugging. Can you recommend how to dump out intermediate results that would indicate the difference between the presence and the absence of the `as` attribute to the `template`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#value-of which says

> The string value of the new text node may be defined either by using
>   the select attribute, or by the sequence constructor (see 5.7 Sequence
>   Constructors) that forms the content of the xsl:value-of element.
>   These are mutually exclusive, and one of them must be present. The way
>   in which the value is constructed is specified in 5.7.2 Constructing
>   Simple Content.

So we need to look at http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#constructing-simple-content and that says "2. Adjacent text nodes in the sequence are merged into a single text node.". So that is what is happening without the `as="xs:string"`, the sequence constructor inside the `xsl:value-of` creates adjacent text nodes which are merged into a single text node. If you have `as="xs:string"` or did `<xsl:sequence select="concat('Fat ', .)"/>` the sequence constructor is of a sequence of primitive string values.

Comment: Martin, thank you for those very useful pointers. So, am I right in saying that without an `as` attribute, the result of an `xsl:template` will always have a data type that comes from the XDM/XPath world (as opposed to the XSchema world)? -- in the case of my duck template, a text node.

Comment: I am not sure what you terms `XDM/XPath world` and `XSchema world` refer to. If you write a template without an `as` attribute its general return type is `item()*` but it can of course return an `xs:dateTime` value for instance by doing `<xsl:sequence select="current-dateTime()"/>`. With XSLT/XPath 2.0 or XQuery 1.0 the data model is sequences of items which can be nodes or primitive values (where the data types of those values are taken from or are an extension of the W3C schema data types). So the distinction "XDM/XPath" opposed to "XSchema" does not exist in my view.

Comment: By "XSchema world", I mean http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/ . By "XDM/XPath world", I mean http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel/. Michael Kay describes these as "two different but overlapping categories [of types]". Your example of `xs:dateTime` being returned is useful (to help push my flawed understanding in the right direction!)